# How to install several Tomcat instances on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I need to have two instances of Tomcat 6 running on Ubuntu 10.04. I know it should be doable pretty simply by something like:

- copy /var/lib/tomcat6 to /var/lib/tomcat6-2
- modify ports in /var/lib/tomcat6-2/conf/server.xml
- copy /etc/init.d/tomcat6 to /etc/init.d/tomcat6-2
- modify /etc/init.d/tomcat6-2...

...but my problem is that I'm unsure what I should modify in /etc/init.d/tomcat6-2. Changing the NAME in the beginning of the file clearly is not enough.

(I'm aware that there is tomcat6-new-instance but I don't want to create instances for users.)

Comment: I can't add a comment to original post, so I will just add my comment as an answer: /var/lib/tomcat-6 has sym links inside, so it is not enough to copy the directory. Anyway, I should still be missing something because even fixing the links it is trying to use configuration from original server.xml.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/13172/multiple-tomcat-instance/729971#729971

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the directives here http://blog.tartachuc.org/2012/01/18/plusieurs-instances-de-tomcat-sur-ubuntu/

There is an ubuntu package called `tomcat6-user` and `tomcat7-user` which gives the command `tomcat6-instance-create` and `tomcat7-instance-create` with which you can create other instances of Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to do this and found the simplest solution to be [this](http://www.altuure.com/2007/12/27/multiple-tomcat/).

Give it a once over and see if this is what your after.

> #### Running multiple tomcat by using a single `catalina_base` and `catalina_home`.
>
> This will make it easy to manage server management
>   to use only one tomcat setup instance
>
> Download tomcat-6+ and unpack it. Modify two configuration files under
>   `conf`:
>
> #### server.xml
>
> replace ports & access log and cluster instance name with variables
>   like:
>
> ```
> <Server port="${tomcat.server.port}1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">...
> <Connector port="${tomcat.server.port}2" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
> ```
>
> connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />...
>
> #### catalina.properties
>
> change log file prefix like
>
> ```
> 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = ${tomcat.server.port}.catalina
> ```
>
> and before you run the command you should set 2 environment variables
>   for each instance like
>
> ```
> set JAVA_OPTS=-Dtomcat.server.port=810
> set CATALINA_TMPDIR=%cd%..work810
> catalina run
>
> set JAVA_OPTS=-Dtomcat.server.port=820
> set CATALINA_TMPDIR=%cd%..work820
> catalina run
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Did you also daemonize the Tomcat instances?

Comment: Not personally, but a client of mine requested information on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

if it's not too late , here is another tutorial that I wrote myself on my blog [www.mycodingpains.com](http://www.mycodingpains.com/how-to-install-multiple-instances-of-tomcat-on-a-single-ubuntu-server/)

I hope this helps someone :)